# Is it true that $\mathcal H^{n-1}(\partial (A \cap B))=\mathcal H^{n-1}((\partial A) \cap B) + \mathcal H^{n-1}( A\cap ( \partial B))$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ subsets of $\mathbb R ^n$, $B=B(x,r)$ an open ball, and denote  the $(n-1)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure in $\mathbb R ^n$ by $\mathcal H^{n-1}$. Also assume that $\mathcal H^{n-1} (\partial A) < + \infty$ (One can assume that $A$ is a set of finite perimeter in necessary).

In this case, is it the following identity holds?

$  \mathcal H^{n-1}(\partial (A \cap B))= \mathcal H^{n-1}((\partial A) \cap B) + \mathcal H^{n-1}( A\cap ( \partial B))$

Comment: What if $A=\Bbb R^n\setminus B$?

Comment: @AlexRavsky Good point! in this case only the second term on the right is non-zero. Let's see the answer in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321524/hausdorff-measure-of-intersection-of-a-ball-and-a-set-in-mathbb-r-n . In Brief, one should replace the first Hausdorff measure with perimeters, and then the result is holds for almost every balls. $P(A \cap B_{\rho}) = P(A, B_{\rho}) + \mathcal H^{n-1}(A \cap \partial B_{\rho})$, a.e. $\rho$. (see the full answer in the link above)